# Which Static Web Generator should i use?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, code-generation, middleman, nanoc

i know average ruby language. i sort out two static web generator **Nanoc** and **Middleman**
my requirements are:-

1. easy to customize
2. easy to learn
3. more resources to learn

so tell me which one will be better for me Nanoc or Middleman?

Thanks for Reading

Comment: I would like to know the pros and cons too.

Comment: I think this question is constructive and can be supported by facts about which generators support which functionality, and what their individual specific purposes are.